# How do i get rid of command not found?

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script

I am new to shell script and I currently am facing an issue that I can't solve which is there is this.

This is the error:

```
vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~$ BookInv
/home/vmw_ubuntu/BookInv: line 155: [=: command not found
```

This is my code (a simple loop)

```
#!/bin/bash
until [$number= "7"];do 
bla bla bla
echo -n "Please enter your option : "
read number
case $number in
7) exit;;
*) echo "Please enter number from 1-7"
esac
done
```

My code still runs perfectly fine only that everytime my loop restarts that error pops up and I can't find a solution to that.

Basically what I want is to get rid of that "command not found" error
is there something wrong with my codes?

The problem is that I have tried omitting the spaces and putting the " on my $number
however the problem still persists.

To the comment about yes the error message complains about

```
[=
```

and by defining does it mean

```
number=0
```

however that does not solve my issue it still shows me the error. I do have other codes in it just some functions but this issue has been there all the while and does not seem to be affected by the functions as I have removed all the functions and tried it.
My program still runs but just keep throwing this error message to me:

```
vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~$ BookInv
/home/vmw_ubuntu/BookInv: line 155: [=: command not found
```

Comment: That `until [$number= "7"];do` looks strange to me; what happens if $number is not defined? Wouldn't that become the `[=` that the error message is complaining about?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no line 155 in your script, I'm guessing it corresponds to line 2 of what you have shown us.

You currently have

```
until [$number = "7"];do
```

Spaces are important in bash, and a test requires spaces within the brackets. `[` is an alias for `test`. So you at least need to have

```
until [ $number = " 7" ]; do
```

As it now stands, since `$number`is empty, bash tries to call a `[=` command. Since `$number` can be empty or contain spaces you should also quote it so that it counts as one and only one argument. The line should be

```
until [ "$number" = "7" ]; do
```

(The quotes around 7 are actually unnecessary but they can't hurt)